# Unable to locate Registered client Asterisk - Kamailio

Tags: asterisk, kamailio

Problem: My main issue is that when I “REGISTER” a client via Kamailio, and I attempt to “Dial” a different endpoint within an Asterisk Dial Plan, Asterisk throws an error stating that the endpoint (the number I am dialing via “Dial”) is not registered or reachable. However, commands like “Playback” do work correctly for the client I “REGISTERED” via Kamailio. 
   E.g. I register client 10001 in Kamailio, I then register another client 10002 in Kamalio; both 10001 and 10002 can exercise an Asterisk Dial Plan which will play videos/audio (No Problem).  But, now I want 10001 to Call (Dial) 10002; it is at this point that Asterisk throws the error “10002 is not registered or reachable”.

I have tried many of the suggestion on many different help boards (several times) but I am still unable to forward a registration from Kamailio to Asterisk.

With my current Kamailio configuration (I do use dispatching), I see , via tcpdump, Asterisk receiving a “REGISTER” request, and Asterisk sends back the “unauthorized” as expected, however, Kamailio does not re-send the “REGISTER” as is customary.  I am not sure of the next step to take, but I feel I have a couple of options.
-   I can continue to try and figure out why Kamailio is not sending the second “REGISTER” (I have not yet been able to figure this out). 
-   Tell Asterisk to not require authentication.  (I am using pjsip and do not know how to not require authentication in Asterisk when the request is from Kamailio).

I have put a lot of time into this one, and I am at a sticking point.  Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Where exactly you stuck? There are ALOT of manuals for integrating and MOST of that is working.

Answer (score 0):

Kamailio is proxy. It SHOULD NOT do send second register unless you EXPLICTLY ask it do that in dialplan.

Dispatcher module is fast processing module. It should not do for you all staff, it just give you suggestion for dispatch.

You should not do check on asterisk for registration, you have send request to kamailio, and kamailio SHOULD do that work(it do much faster and HAVE info).

Main issue is:

asterisk main goal - give easy to understand platform for begginers. So anyone can get working pbx for free. It work on top level, with calls.

kamailio main goal is PERFOMANCE. It is not for begginer, you need have solid understanding of sip protocol, not just know that you want call. You have define what to do on packets level.